# React + mobx How to fetch data from API

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, mobx

I want to fetch data from an API within my `React` app using `Mobx`. The API is build with PHP. Since I run my app on `localhost:8080` and the API forexample runs on `localhost/restapi/public/api/releases` how can I fetch the API data then?

Here is my React and Mobx code:

```
import { observable, action, async } from "mobx"

export default class ReleaseState {
   @observable releases = [];

   constructor() {
      this.getReleases()
   }

   @action async getReleases() {
       return await fetch('/restapi/public/api/releases').then((data) => {
        //...
       })
   }    

}

const releaseState = new ReleaseState();
```

As mentioned before, my App runs on `localhost:8080`, the API is served on `localhost/restapi/public/api/releases` - any help is appreciated

Comment: The two servers run on different ports, so this is most likely a CORS issue. You didn't even state what the problem is though.

Comment: Did you try : `http://localhost/restapi/public/api/releases` as url instead or a relative one?

Comment: @C.Rast then I get the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error - but I get your point

Comment: You'll need to configure your API to accept CORS requests, as @ChrisG stated, and at least on localhost.

Comment: @Steve you can't use a relative URL to request resources from a different server. If you use the absolute address, you get an easily googleable error with a straightforward solution. You PHP api needs `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`